# How to make Firefox 9 read stdin?

Tags: firefox, stdin

[An earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24931/how-to-make-firefox-read-stdin) got several nice answers involving stdin, none of which work in Firefox 9.0.1 (**Edit**: because I didn't read that you had to start a *new Firefox process* to make them work (thanks @manatwork):

- `echo '<h1>hello, world</h1>' | firefox /dev/fd/0` results in a new tab with the URL `file:///dev/null` and no text.
- `cat | firefox /dev/fd/0` results in a new tab with the URL `file:///dev/null` and no text. After typing a single line of text and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> it terminates and still doesn't show anything in the new tab.
- `firefox <( echo '<h1>hello, world</h1>' )` opens up a new tab with my profile folder, of all things.

Is there any way to make this work in Firefox 9.0.1 or newer?

As to the reason behind, it would be nice to be able to generate markup which is only stored in memory (barring swapping), and guarantee that there is no left-overs even in case of a power cut.

Comment: Those work in Firekox 9.0.1 too, with the same restriction as earlier: “If your firefox command is actually starting Firefox instead of talking with an already-running Firefox instance”, as mentioned there by Jander.

Answer (score 3):

I found a program called [`bcat`](https://github.com/rtomayko/bcat) written in ruby. Couple of examples can be accessed via [this link](http://rtomayko.github.com/bcat/bcat.1.html).

Comment: This is absolutely terrific! On *buntu it is included in the standard repositories `sudo aptitude install ruby-bcat`.

Answer (score 2):

Followin @userunknown suggestion, in case your `/tmp` is not a `tmpfs` type filesystem, then you can use `/dev/shm` or create your own `tmpfs` filesystem (both are held in memory):

```
/mnt/tmp && mount -t tmpfs none /mnt/tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

> As to the reason behind, it would be nice to be able to generate markup which is only stored in memory (barring swapping), and guarantee that there is no left-overs even in case of a power cut.

I don't know for other Unixes, but on Linux, `/tmp` is deleted on every startup/shutdown. So

```
echo "<html><head><title> FooTemp </title></head></html>" \ 
    > /tmp/foo.html && firefox /tmp/foo.html && rm /tmp/foo.html
```

works fine for me.

More convenient maybe: Delete the file immediately after opening it in Firefox, I tested it:

```
echo "<html><head><title> FooTemp </title></head></html>" > \
 /tmp/f3.html && (firefox /tmp/f3.html & sleep 3 ; rm /tmp/f3.html)
```

Give it some seconds to render it, and then delete it. Works like a charm for me. No /tmp/f3.html to be seen with `ls /tmp/*html` after 3 seconds, but visible in the browser.

Comment: That still leaves a file on the HD while Firefox is running and even afterwards if the process is killed before `rm`, which was the point of the question.

Comment: @l0b0: I updated my answer; it now contains a solution where the temporary file is deleted after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 9, and greater, support [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). Any HTML will need a `data:text/html,` prefix.

```
shell ~> firefox -new-tab 'data:text/html,<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>'
```

Not quite stdin, but it should work

```
shell ~> firefox -new-tab "data:text/html,"`cat myfile.txt`
```

Comment: The first example did not work on Firefox 14.0.1 - It simply opened a new window (not tab) with my default home page.