# How to associate markdown files with a web browser?

Tags: bash, html, .desktop, markdown, pandoc

Out of GUI-based software like ReText or Formiko, and using just a *command-line tool* like pandoc, is it possible to open markdown files (MIME type association) as an HTML file in a web browser, without any browser-addon too?

Notice that the original markdown file may include links to images or any kind of resources. Therefore, this process should be on-fly (stdout?), without saving the output HTML file to somewhere else like `/tmp/` directory.

And how can such a command be included in a `.desktop` file?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86897/236063):

```bsh
pandoc README.md | firefox "data:text/html;base64,$(base64 -w 0 <&0)"
# or
python3 -m markdown README.md | firefox "data:text/html;base64,$(base64 -w 0 <&0)"
```

So, you can create a function:

```
mdopen(){ pandoc "$1" | firefox "data:text/html;base64,$(base64 -w 0 <&0)"; }
```

Usage:

```
mdopen README.md
```

---

Alternative: Use [`grip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24942367). It opens a local webserver to serve markdown-files.

```bsh
$ pip install grip
$ grip
[...]
* Running on http://localhost:6419/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When you point your browser to that location, you can see your markdown files.

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately, it blocks external resources! … Seems like [this is the reason](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/11/27/blocking-top-level-navigations-data-urls-firefox-59/), any _safe workaround_ here?

Comment: This should work even better with `pandoc --self-containted`, as that will cause pandoc to put all resources into the HTML.

Comment: @tarleb Interesting! However, for my use case, "Argument list too long" :(

Comment: @AnasR. try with a temporary file?

Comment: @tarleb Yes, it works fine, but not when using a massive css file.